# Django dynamic urls / Sitemap builder

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a site map builder in django.
This would consist of a model that looks something like this:

```
class SiteMap(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256) # The title of the page
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256) # url fragement, .../url/...
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=256) # Like forum, livechat, etc...
    under_page = models.ForeignKey(SiteMap, blank=True) # page this exists under
```

All of the views would be preexisting so my question is how do I direct the url created from the models into the views.

If this method is completely wrong don't be afraid to suggest a completely new way of doing this.

Comment: Would you use the [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)?

Comment: The suggestion is not to re invent the wheel https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Comment: I figured something as much. Any suggestions on how to implement this into the admin control panel?